# davfs2: Mount multiple webDAV from same server using different credentials

Tags: webdav, davfs2

How can I accomplish a set up where a webDAV service on a single server is mounted multiple times using different credentials?

I am imagining something like this kind of set up that allows davfs2 to correctly associate the credentials with the mount

`/etc/fstab`

```
https://server.com/dav /mnt1 davfs rw 0 0
https://server.com/dav /mnt2 davfs rw 0 0
```

`/etc/davfs2/secrets`

```
https://server.com/dav user@email.com password
https://server.com/dav user2@differentemail.com differentpassword
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your secrets file needs to show the mount locations. In my install

```
/mnt1 user@email.com password

/mnt2 user2@differentemail.com differentpassword
```

See below for more details.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Davfs

Comment: I change line in my `/etc/davfs2/secrets` to: `https://server.com/dav /mnt1 user@email.com password` and get error `sbin/mount.davfs:/etc/davfs2/secrets:1: malformed line`. What did I do wrong?